# Conditional redirect on an angular dart page

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-2

I have a page  (A)  in Angular Dart 2  that would be  visible based on a condition.   If the condition is  false, it should  redirect to page  B

I can implement this logic  using router.navigate  in   onActivate  or onInIt or other hooks.  However,  router.navigate  returns  a future.  Thus  all  the router and life cycle hooks and  any methods referenced in  template  still get called.

How can I completely bypass page A  and get it  redirected to  page B  if the condition is false?   canNavigate() and CanDeactivate  would  work only if the user  navigateS to PAGE A  via  some  other page.  It won't  work  if the user bookmarks and  directly visits page A